# a Pythonic implementation of string contraction which lists characters as they appear and their counts?

Tags: python

I implemented string contraction which lists the characters of a string with their respective counts. So, for example, the string "aadddza" becomes "a2d3z1a1". Can you offer suggestions on making what I have Pythonic?

```
def string_contraction(input_string):

    if type(input_string) != str:
        print("Not a string")
        return

    input_string = str.lower(input_string)

    prev = input_string[0]
    s = ""
    i = 0

    for lett in input_string:
        if lett == prev:
            i += 1
        else:
            s += prev+str(i)
            prev = lett
            i = 1
    s += lett+str(i)

    return(s)
```

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you can make use of the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class and create `c = Counter(input_string)` and do your analysis on that object.

Comment: Try Codereview?

Comment: If you want people to make your working code cleaner, and you don't have a specific question, the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site is usually a better fit.

Comment: @SunnyPatel `Counter` wouldn't work here because it seems like OP is counting consecutive occurrences.

Comment: Google "python run length encoding", and in particular note the uses of itertools.groupby

Comment: @pault Ah right, I just noticed that. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is also noteworthy.

Comment: The aforementioned `itertools.groupby` solution would be: `"".join([x + str(len(list(y))) for x, y in itertools.groupby(input_string)])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function can do the "hard part" for you.  Here's an example ("rle" is short for "run length encoding"):

```
def rle(s):
    from itertools import groupby
    return "".join(letter + str(len(list(group)))
                   for letter, group in groupby(s))
```

Then:

```
>>> rle("aadddza")
'a2d3z1a1'
```

It may take a while staring at the docs to figure out how this works - `groupby()` is quite logical, but not simple.  In particular, the second element of each two-tuple it generates is not a list of matching elements from the original iterable, but is itself an iterable that *generates* a sequence of matching elements from the original iterable.  Your application only cares about the *number* of matching elements.  So the code uses `list(group)` to turn the iterable into a list, and then applies `len()` to that to get the number.